# How is this taylor equation derived?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative

It is a multi-variable function $I(x,y,t)$ and its 1st-order Taylor expansion should be
$$I(x+\Delta x, y+\Delta y, t+\Delta t) \approx I(x,y,t) + \left(\frac{\partial I}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial I}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt} +\frac{\partial I}{\partial t} \frac{dt}{dt}\right)(\Delta x, \Delta y, \Delta t).$$
$I$ here is actually $I(t)$?

However, I noticed in a book a smilar function is expanded like $$I(x+\mathrm{d}x,y+\mathrm{d}y,t+\mathrm{d}t) \approx I(x,y,t) + \frac{\partial I}{\partial x}\mathrm{d}x + \frac{\partial I}{\partial y}\mathrm{d}y + \frac{\partial I}{\partial t}\mathrm{d}t.$$
Why it is not
$$I(x+\mathrm{d}x,y+\mathrm{d}y,t+\mathrm{d}t) \approx I(x,y,t) + \left(\frac{\partial I}{\partial x}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{\partial I}{\partial y}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{\partial I}{\partial t}\right)(\mathrm{d}x,\mathrm{d}y,\mathrm{d}t)?$$

Comment: The second formula looks like the correct one to me. The others look like something you would get for $I = I(t) = I(x(t), y(t), t)$ if you expand this in $t$.

Comment: @DanDoe How is the 2nd one derived.

Comment: Usual multi-dimensional [Taylor Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables) for independent variables $x, y, t$.

Comment: $$ I'=(\frac{\partial I}{\partial x} ,  \frac{\partial I}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial I}{\partial t})(dx, dy, dt)$$?

Comment: What is written in formulas 1 and 3 makes no sense. What is the meaning of $(\Delta x,\Delta y,\Delta z)$?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin. Thanks for feedback. I am not good at math. For me, suppose that $\mathbf{v} = [x,y,z]$ we then have $I(\mathbf{v})$. According to Taylor expansion, we should get $$I(\mathbf{v} + \Delta \mathbf{v} ) \approx I(\mathbf{v}) + I'(\mathbf{v}) \Delta \mathbf{v} \\ = I + (\frac{\partial I}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial I}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial I}{\partial t})\Delta \mathbf{v} $$ I cannot get the second equaqtion